# How to find the maximum value for these values

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I have some states and their population and want to print out the largest state along with the number of its population.

This is the information :

```
NSW 87
QLD 49
SA 14
VIC 54
WA 19
```

I want to find the maximum i.e `NSW 87` , to be printed out. I tried using `max` function:

```
for i,j in zip(unique10,count10):
    print(max(i,j))
```

but it didn't help:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.str_'
```

Comment: can u edit your question and add a more detailed code

Comment: What should I add guide me

Comment: the information you stated in the question, in what format is it, a list or a dict?

Comment: Oh that is an array.                                 ['NSW' 'QLD' 'SA' 'VIC' 'WA']
[87 49 14 54 19]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use built-in `max` and `zip`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([['NSW' ,'QLD' ,'SA', 'VIC', 'WA'], [87, 49, 14, 54, 19]])
arr
# array([['NSW', 'QLD', 'SA', 'VIC', 'WA'],
#        ['87', '49', '14', '54', '19']], dtype='<U3')

max(zip(*arr), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Output:

```
('NSW', '87')
```

Comment: This works but I am not quite familiar with lambda function.

Comment: @SibtainReza It is telling `max` function to calculate the max based on the second element of tuples of `('NSW', 87)`, `('QLD', 49)`, and so on.

Comment: Might as well drop numpy, that only makes it more confusing.

Comment: @BramVanroy I used numpy only because the OP's original thing is in `np.ndarray`. Purpose of this is to demonstrate the conventional `max` + `zip` works just fine when it comes to `numpy` :)